How to find a new Probability Mass Function?
In my Mid Semester exam I got a question asking to build a probability mass function of some discrete random variable such that pmf takes countably infinite many values and pmf is not of any well known distribution?
After completing the rest of the paper, I spent half an hour on it but what I found was just a variation of Geometric Distribution.
Can someone explain how to think of such new things, means I know that $\Sigma p_x(x) = 1$ and $0\leq p_x(x) \leq1$. But how to find something new.

What an odd question to ask on an exam.

Welcome to MSE. That's a very interesting question to put on an exam. One thing that always works is that given the requirement $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n =1$ and $0\leq p_n\leq 1$, the series converges absolutely and you can thus reorder the summation, defining a “new” pmf. So e.g. if $p_n = p(1-p)^n$ is the pmf of a random variable following a geometric distribution, for any bijection $\nu \colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ the map $q_n = p_{\nu(n)}$ satisfies $0\leq q_n\leq 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q_n=1$ and is thus a pmf.

Perhaps you could just take an arbitrary sequence of non-negative values with a finite sum and rescale it.
So for example for $n \in {1,2,3,\ldots}$: $$\mathbb P(X=n) = \frac{\log(n+\pi)(2+\sin n ) / n^4}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \log(n+\pi)(2+\sin i) / i^4}$$ would satisfy the question.

@Henry How did you derive this sequence?

@Henry Apart from you accidentally using $n$ once instead of $i$ in the denominator, that's great. Of course, it helps to say $P(X=n)=f(n)/\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)$ with $f$ defined separately, so that doesn't happen.

To extend on the comment from @Henry, I thought of something. Let $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$ be a convergent series such that

$\forall n: 0\leq a_n$,
$a_n$ takes countably many different values.

Let $a = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} a_n$ , then $\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}\frac{a_n}{a}=1$ by the convergence of $a$. Furthermore, $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n \leq a$, as all summands are non-negative, and thus $\forall n:0\leq \frac{a_n}{a}\leq 1$, hence $\frac{a_n}{a}$ is a pmf.
If you need a corresponding probability space, the measure
$$
\mathbb P(B) := \sum_{n\in B}\frac{a_n}{a}
$$
on the measurable space $(\mathbb N,\mathcal P(\mathbb N))$ has $\frac{a_n}{a}$ as a density with respect to the counting measure.

Thanks for the explanation

To have an answer without an normalization, this is what I would try.
We define a pmf on the positive integers this way.
(1) $a_1$ is the outcome of a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
(2) Given $a_1,...,a_i$, let $a_{i+1}$ be an outcome of a uniform distribution on $[0,1 - \Sigma_i a_i]$.

That's really unique approach

But how would you set an exact probability value for a random variable. As much I understood we are taking probility for X = 0 from (0,1) let a1 then for X = 1 from (0,1-a1)   and so on but we need an exact value to say its a pmf

@RishiVerma, perhaps, but the question is vague enough to not need that kind of a specification.
